# How to stop beeps once and for all

Tags: debian, audio

I put this in my `/etc/rc.local` on Debian, using XFCE, and it seemed to work for years to block my system from beeping on error:

```
modprobe -r pcspkr
```

But now, they're baaack... the beeps, although now they come through my attached speakers. How can I stop all beeps forever?

Comment: Can you give us some examples of when this happens? Is it in the terminal only? Have you tried `xset b off`?

Comment: `xset b off` (without the `-`) in X11, and `printf '\033[10;0]'` in the Linux terminal (e.g. `[ "$TERM" = linux ] && printf '\033[10;0]'` in `/etc/profile.d/shut-up.sh`)

Comment: Thanks, @UncleBilly, `xset b` indeed, not `-b` (I edited my previous comment). I just typed it from memory and misremembered. I've had that in my bashrc files for 20 years now so I forget! :)

Comment: It's intermittent.  Next time it happens I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: But I've had "xset -b" since forever in "/etc/xdg/xfce4/xinitrc"

Comment: The first beep is happening before it gets to the first prompt, somewhere in System D's machinery.  Funny that this would start happening after years of peace and quiet.  The bleeding beep is so loud it makes me jump out of my skin.

Comment: Here's something: it happens after return from hibernation.  Retyping 'xset b off' cures it :) ... but I'm expecting it to remain off since that's what I've set in /etc/rc.local.  Is there some script that's read after return from hibernation?  I'll throw 'xset b off' in there.

Answer (score 0):

I put:

```
xset b off
```

in /etc/hibernate/common.conf

... and that's solved the problem.